# Proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\binom{n(n-1)}{10n}}{n^{cn}}=\infty$.

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\binom{n(n-1)}{10n}}{n^{cn}}=\infty$ where $c$ is a constant less than 1.  I've tried expanding out the binomial but it just looks like a mess and I don't think it's productive.  I also know that some similar problems can be analyzed using Stirling's approximation.  But I think this is useful only when the limit is finite, because we would use something like $\binom{n(n-1)}{10n}\le \binom{n(n-1)}{n(n-1)/2}$ and also use $n^{cn}=2^{cn\log_2 n}$ or something like it.  But because of the direction of the inequality, I don't think this can be used to prove that the limit goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the expression as

$$\frac{(n^2 - n)!}{(n^2 - 11n)!} \times \frac{1}{(10n)!} \times \frac{1}{(n)^n} \times \frac{(n)^n}{(n)^{(cn)}}.\tag1$$

Since $c < 1,$ then regardless of whether $c$ is negative, the rightmost factor in (1) above will never be $< 1.$  Therefore,
as $n \to \infty$, the rightmost factor may be ignored.

Therefore, I am going to ignore the rightmost factor, and prove that as $n \to \infty,$ the product of the 1st 3 factors in (1) above will grow unbounded.

---

**Note**
As $r \to \infty$, the geometric mean of the numbers $\{1,2,\cdots, r\}$ will approach $\frac{r}{e}$, from above, and the geometric mean will always be strictly less than the arithmetic mean of the numbers $\{1,2,\cdots, r\}$, which may be reasonably approximated by $\frac{r}{2}$.

Examine the 1st factor in (1) above, as $n \to \infty.$

The geometric mean of the numerator will always be greater than $\frac{n^2 - n}{e}$, while the geometric mean of the denominator will always be less than $\frac{n^2 - 11n}{2}.$

Therefore, as $n \to \infty$, the leftmost factor in (1) above will always be greater than

$$\left[\frac{n^2 - n}{e}\right]^{(n^2 - n)} \times 
\left[\frac{2}{n^2 - 11n}\right]^{(n^2 - 11n)}.\tag2$$

Clearly, for $n$ large enough, you will have that

$\displaystyle \left[\frac{n^2 - n}{e}\right] \times 
\left[\frac{2}{n^2 - 11n}\right] > 1.$

Therefore, for $n$ large enough, the expression in (2) above will exceed

$$\left[\frac{n^2 - n}{e}\right]^{(10n)}.\tag3$$

In similar analysis, the 2nd factor in (1) above will always be greater than

$$\left[\frac{2}{10n}\right]^{(10n)}.\tag4$$

Putting (3) and (4) together with the 3rd factor in (1) above, you have that for large enough $n$, the product of the three leftmost factors in (1) above will always exceed

$$\left[\frac{2(n^2 - n)}{e(10n)}\right]^{(10n)} \times \frac{1}{n^n}.\tag5$$

In (5) above, the rightmost factor may be re-written as

$\displaystyle \left[\frac{1}{n^{(1/10)}}\right]^{(10n)}.$

This implies that (5) above may be re-written as

$$\left[\frac{2(n^2 - n)}{e(10)n^{(1.1)}}\right]^{(10n)}.\tag6$$

With $\frac{2}{10e}$ a fixed number, it is clear that as $n \to \infty, ~(n^2 - n)$ will dwarf $n^{(1.1)}.$

Therefore, the expression in (6) above will go to infinity as $n \to \infty$, and therefore, so will the expression in (1) above.